# QML draw grid on map

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have to draw squares on a map as to create a grid. Such squares should be related to the "geographic area" (not as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641161/is-it-possible-to-create-a-map-grid-in-qml), where the grid is simply superimposed to the map).

The grid should be visible in every area of the world but for efficiency purposes I'm currently rendering only the squares lying in the visible area. The solution that I've implemented works but it's extremely unefficient. I'm looking for a better approach.

At the moment I create a `ListModel` which contains all the tiles points. Such `ListModel` is populated again as soon as map VisibleRegionChanged is triggered. This is the most expensive operation.

The `ListModel` is passed to a `MapItemView` which contains a `MapPolygon` that performs the actual render.

```
Map {
    ...

    onMapReadyChanged: miv.model = tilesModel
    onVisibleRegionChanged: {
        tilesModel.clear();

        const visibleTL = map.visibleRegion.boundingGeoRectangle().topLeft;
        const visibleTL_m = QtPositioning.coordToMercator(visibleTL);
        const visibleBR = map.visibleRegion.boundingGeoRectangle().bottomRight;
        const visibleBR_m = QtPositioning.coordToMercator(visibleBR);

        const xStarting = Math.floor(visibleTL_m.x/tilesModel.tilesSize)*tilesModel.tilesSize
        const yStarting = Math.floor(visibleTL_m.y/tilesModel.tilesSize)*tilesModel.tilesSize
        const xEnding = visibleBR_m.x
        const yEnding = visibleBR_m.y

        for(var r = xStarting; r < xEnding; r+=tilesModel.tilesSize){
            for(var c = yStarting; c < yEnding; c+=tilesModel.tilesSize){
                tilesModel.append({
                    tile_tl_x: r,
                    tile_tl_y: c
                })
            }
        }

    }

    ListModel {
        id: tilesModel
        property real tilesSize: 0.0005

        Component.onCompleted: {
            const visibleTL = map.visibleRegion.boundingGeoRectangle().topLeft;
            const visibleTL_m = QtPositioning.coordToMercator(visibleTL);
            const visibleBR = map.visibleRegion.boundingGeoRectangle().bottomRight;
            const visibleBR_m = QtPositioning.coordToMercator(visibleBR);

            const xStarting = Math.floor(visibleTL_m.x/tilesSize)*tilesSize
            const yStarting = Math.floor(visibleTL_m.y/tilesSize)*tilesSize
            const xEnding = visibleBR_m.x
            const yEnding = visibleBR_m.y

            for(var r = xStarting; r < xEnding; r+=tilesSize){
                for(var c = yStarting; c < yEnding; c+=tilesSize){
                    append({
                        tile_tl_x: r,
                        tile_tl_y: c
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    }
    
    MapItemView {
        id: miv
        model: tilesModel

        delegate: Component {
            MapPolygon {

                function fromTL(x,y){
                    const ts = tilesModel.tilesSize;
                    return [QtPositioning.mercatorToCoord(Qt.point(x,y)),
                            QtPositioning.mercatorToCoord(Qt.point(x+ts,y)),
                            QtPositioning.mercatorToCoord(Qt.point(x+ts,y+ts)),
                            QtPositioning.mercatorToCoord(Qt.point(x,y+ts))];
                }

                path: fromTL(tile_tl_x, tile_tl_y);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this not the best approach. Could you suggest me a better way to achieve this?

This is the result I want:
[image: final result]